# Unity2D moveSpeed difference between Windows and Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am working on an infinite runner for mobile where the movement speed accelerates after time. But for some reason, the movement speed/acceleration is not the same on Android compared to Windows. e.g. after 10 sec, my movement speed is 10 on Windows but still 8 on Android and I don't know why.

Here is the movement code:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    //Movement
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(2f, 0f, 0f);
    transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    
    //Max Speed, stop acceleration at 25
    if(moveSpeed <= 25){
        moveSpeed = moveSpeed * acceleration;
    }else{
        moveSpeed = moveSpeed * 1;
    }
    speedText.text = moveSpeed.ToString();

    Jump();
    CheckSpeed();   

}
```

Comment: Your speed equation is wrong.  Speed = Speed + (Acceleration * Time).

Comment: You mean the "moveSpeed = moveSpeed * acceleration;" ? i tried ur approach but he just stopped moving

Comment: You have to multiply by Time.deltaTime.  The reason it is different on your two devices is because  they have different framerates.   The line should literally be `movespeed += acceleration * Time.deltaTime * accelerationRate`  You will need to make a new variable for the acceleratonRate to control how fast it accelerates.  You might notice this looks like what you have for position, because it is!  Acceleration is the rate velocity changes over time, just like velocity is the rate position changes over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The android build is probably running at a lower framerate than the windows build. Since you multiply the speed every frame without adjusting for framerate the speed will increase slower when playing on a lower framerate. There are 2 ways of solving this.

---

### Solution 1

Multiply `moveSpeed` with `acceleration` to the power of `Time.deltaTime` instead of just `acceleration`.

```
if(moveSpeed <= 25){
    moveSpeed = moveSpeed * Mathf.Pow(acceleration, Time.deltaTime);
}
```

This will always adjust `moveSpeed` at the same rate, regardless of framerate. Note that while in the original script `acceleration` specified how much it would accelerate every frame, whereas now it specifies how much it accelerates every second. Make sure to increase `acceleration` or it could look like it's not moving at all.

---

### Solution 2

Move your acceleration code from `LateUpdate` to `FixedUpdate`.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(moveSpeed <= 25){
        moveSpeed = moveSpeed * acceleration;
    }
}
```

While `LateUpdate` is run every frame, `FixedUpdate` is run at a fixed speed. Therefore `moveSpeed` will accelerate at the same rate regardless of framerate.

---

Also, you can change `moveSpeed = moveSpeed *` to `moveSpeed *=`. You also don't need

```
else{
    moveSpeed = moveSpeed * 1;
}
```

since the value of `moveSpeed` will be the same either way.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the second solution and it worked^^